# How can choose the five largest values in an array and put them in a new array?

Tags: arrays

How can choose the five largest values in an array and put them in a new array?

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 1, 19 };
int[] largestValues = new int[5];

for (int i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(largestValues[i]);
}
```

Comment: In which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

For Eg.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i;
    int large[] = new int[5];
    int array[] = { 33, 55, 13, 46, 87, 42, 10, 34, 43, 56 };
    int max = 0, index;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        max = array[0];
        index = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (max < array[i]) {
                max = array[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        large[j] = max;
        array[index] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        System.out.println("Largest " + j +  " : " + large[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does "Integer.MIN-VALUE" do?